# Trying to compile binaries with static flag?

Tags: compiling, command-line

i am working over Gem 5 simulator on ubuntu OS and i need to compile any program with static flag for this i am using this command:

```
[/work/gem5] alpha-linux-gnueabi-gcc –DUNIX –o queens queens.c –static
```

where `queens.c` is my c file but i am unable to do that because every time it is showing as command not found , I have also tried to install it through `sudo apt-get` but it is not working.

Comment: alpha-linux-gnueabi-gcc does not exist on your path. If it's in the directory you are in preface the command with ./ for example `./alpha-linux-gnueabi-gcc –DUNIX –o queens queens.c –static `

Answer (score 1):

remove the dash front of static and type dash '-' again. I think the ASCI code differs.

Comment: Yeah, a bunch of those look like en-dashes, not hyphens.